# Possibility to "scrape" or "forward" traces (not logs, not metrics) for Spring Boot 3

Tags: spring-boot, opentracing, distributed-tracing, micrometer-tracing

I would like to find a way to scrape or forward the traces generated by Spring Boot 3 app.

We have a Spring Boot 3 app that does not make outbound HTTP calls. The app only takes requests and saves data in DBs. When saving to DB, it generates traces, representing the interaction with DBs.

This same app generates application logs. For those, we use promtail / splunk forwarder to tail and forward the logs to the log aggregation backend. This is transparent to the application layer.

This same app generates application metrics. For those, we use prometheus, and expose an endpoint, so prometheus comes and scrapes the metrics. The application layer is not sending things on its own.

In the above two cases, the app itself is not making any outbound calls to send the logs or the metrics.

The application does not have any HTTP clients, and on the network layer, for security reasons, the app itself will not be able to communicate out.

The issue arises when it comes to traces. It seems there is no way to scrape or forward the traces, only for the app to create some network outbound calls, which we cannot do.

Is there a way for Spring Boot apps to not send the traces directly?

Comment: Spans (traces) are push based by nature. Can you publish them "locally" to a collector/proxy?